# DatePicker in modal Bootstrap is shown UNDER the modal window but not UPFRONT

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, modal-dialog

I've got a modal bootstrap window with a datepicker that is shown under the modal window and not upfront so as to let selection of date. The modal is:

```
<div id="DateDiv" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <!-- Date Pickers-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="DateFrom"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input class="form-control span2" type="text" id="DateFrom" name="DateFrom" value="" >
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonFechasSeleccionadas" role="button" onclick="SelectedDates(this); return false;">Buscar</a>
            </div>

            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

The javascript I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Date Picker DateFrom
    $('#DateFrom').datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() > now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {

    }).data('datepicker');


});
```

There is an input text which shows modal when selected:

```
$('#InputText').on("focus", function () {
                    $('#DateDiv').modal('show');
                });
```

The thing is that, when the input text 'InputText' is clicked, the modal actually shows up, but when clicking on the date field 'DateFrom' the calendar is shown grey and disabled under the modal window.

Any idea please???

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved by adding style with high z-index and also important

```
<style type="text/css">
        #ui-datepicker-div {
            z-index: 9999 !important; /* must be > than popup window */
        }    
</style>
```